# Checking if an array of Observables have completed in a synchronous way?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

In my app I would like the "Save" button to not do anything if any of the data in my form hasn't finished loading yet. The data sources in my form are both `Observables`: `source1$` and `source2$`

Since the user can click the button at any time I want to be able to check if any Web API requests are pending and if they are then do nothing -- otherwise save.

I'm imagining something like this:

```
saveButton_onClicked() {
    if (// source1$ and source2$ are completed) {
        this.saveForm();
    }
}
```

At any time either of these observables could be assigned to a new observable (when the data is refreshed, for example) and I don't think a `forkJoin` would work here since I need to know *in real time* if the form should be saved or not, I don't want the click event to be waiting for a `forkJoin` observable to resolve.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I think the easiest way is using `forkJoin` and the `finalize` operator and not checking the source Observables themselves but rather creating a property eg. `loading` that you can check anytime and see whether there are pending Observables:

```
whatever() {
  this.loading = true;

  forkJoin(source1$, source2$)
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => this.loading = false)
    )
    .subscribe();
}

saveButton_onClicked() {
  if (!this.loading) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Will I need to destroy the old `forkJoin` and create a new one every time I assign `source1$` or `source2$` to a new `Observable`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are many ways to skin a cat.
Some are more elegant than others. I prefer to keep the number of extra observable properties to a minimum, that in this case seems to be 2. I would add a property`isRunningRequest$`, whose emitted value is a flag, true if there are currently running operations. This flag would be alimented by an aggregation over another observable, `asyncAction$`, to be used to keep track of the currently running actions:

```
export class AsyncActionData {
  actionType: 'start' | 'end';
  actionToken: string;
}

    public asyncAction$ = new Subject<AsyncActionData>();

    public isRunningRequest$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor(...) {
        this.asyncAction$
            .pipe(
                // we keep an array of currently running actions, and add
                // or remove from the array according to the action type
                scan((arr: string[], action: AsyncActionData) => {
                    return action.actionType === 'start'
                        ? arr.concat(action.actionToken)
                        : arr.filter(action => action !== action.actionToken);
                }, []),
                map(arr => arr.length === 0 ? false : true)
            )
            .subscribe(requestsAreRunning => this.isRunningRequest$.next(requestsAreRunning));
    }
```

When you perform an action, you emit events on `asyncAction$`:

```
this.asyncAction$.next({actionType: 'start', actionToken: 'action1'});
this.http.post(...)
   .subscribe(result => ...,
              null,
              () => this.asyncAction$.next({actionType: 'end', actionToken: 'action1'})
   );
```

(all code untested, but the idea should be sound)

See [here](http://rxmarbles.com/#scan) and [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) for documentation about the `scan` operator.

Comment: _"I prefer to keep the number of extra observables to a minimum, so I would use an extra observable"_ I like your kind of humor :D

Comment: :P with RxJs the solution is always to add some transformed observable ;) Got to rephrase, though.

Comment: If I were to use this solution, what would the code look like that checks to see if any actions are pending?

Comment: You can just use an ngIf on “isRunningRequest$ | async” or subscribe to isRunningRequest$ to get a true when there are requests and a false when there is none. Still, don’t use code that you don’t understand;)